# Submit a rails form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
 <% category.child_categories.sort_by(&:name).each do |child_category| %>
     <%= form_tag (search_path), :method => "get", class: "search-form" do %>
         <label for="checkData" style="cursor: pointer;" class="search">
           <%= hidden_field_tag :shop_search, child_category.id %>
             <i class="fas fa-search"></i> <%= child_category.name %>
          </label>
     <%= submit_tag '', :style => "display: none;" %>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

When I click on a label and if the cookies[:coordinates] does exist, then the form gets submitted with `$(this).parent('form.search-form').trigger('submit.rails');`:

```
$(".search").click(function(e){
    <% if cookies[:coordinates].blank? %>
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie, displayError);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by the browser you are currently using. Supported browsers: Chrome 5.0, Firefox 3.5, Internet Explorer 9.0, Opera 10.60, Safari 5.0");
        }


    function setGeoCookie(position) {
        let cookieName = "coordinates";
        let now = new Date();
        let time = now.getTime();
        time += 3600 * 5000;
        now.setTime(time);
        let cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
        document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookie_val + '; path=/';
        $(this).parent('form.search-form').trigger('submit.rails');
    }


    function displayError(error) {
        let errors = {
            1: 'error',
            2: 'Position unavailable',
            3: 'Request timeout'
        };
        alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        window.location.reload(true)

    }
    getLocation();
    <% else%>
    $(this).parent('form.search-form').trigger('submit.rails');
    <% end %>
});
```

And when the cookies[:coordinates] doesn't exist I have to create the cookie first and then trigger the form inside the `function setGeoCookie`. But for some odd reason the form is not being submitted. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `$(this)` has another scope. Try to store the form before executing the function. Then it sould work.

```
$(".search").click(function(e){
    var form = $(this).parent('form.search-form')
    <% if cookies[:coordinates].blank? %>
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie, displayError);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by the browser you are currently using. Supported browsers: Chrome 5.0, Firefox 3.5, Internet Explorer 9.0, Opera 10.60, Safari 5.0");
        }


    function setGeoCookie(position) {
        let cookieName = "coordinates";
        let now = new Date();
        let time = now.getTime();
        time += 3600 * 5000;
        now.setTime(time);
        let cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
        document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookie_val + '; path=/';
        form.trigger('submit.rails');
    }


    function displayError(error) {
        let errors = {
            1: 'error',
            2: 'Position unavailable',
            3: 'Request timeout'
        };
        alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        window.location.reload(true)

    }
    getLocation();
    <% else%>
    form.trigger('submit.rails');
    <% end %>
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Archer... it works just fine! :)))